# How to persist proxy settings for Chrome on Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I've added some proxy settings in google-chrome.desktop:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

by adding them to each "Exec" entry (there are three):

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --proxy-server="localhost:3128" --proxy-bypass-list="localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

But: With each update of Chrome (and there are a lot...) these settings are overwritten. Is there a way to persist the proxy settings, making them survive an update?

Answer (score 0):

Current workaround: I set the proxy settings with this command:

```
sudo sed -i.bak '/^Exec\=/ s/$/ \-\-proxy\-server\="localhost\:3128" \-\-proxy\-bypass\-list\="localhost\,127\.0\.0\.1"/' /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

Warning: This doesn't check if there's already a `--proxy...` declared in the processed lines. However `-i.bak` creates a backup of the file ;)